# Insert play icon with space into page title -- Like YouTube

Tags: javascript, jquery, unicode, title, html5-audio

So I got this little code [I found online](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/Tt48M/10/show/light/) to display a unicode play icon into the page title bar like YouTube does when you play and pause a video:

```
$('audio').on('play pause', function () {
    var player = $('audio')[0];
    PrependPageTitle(player);
});

function PrependPageTitle(player) {
    if (player.paused) {
        if (document.title.charAt(0) === '\u25ba')
            document.title = document.title.slice(1);
    } else {
        if (document.title.charAt(0) !== '\u25ba')
            document.title = '\u25BA' + document.title;
    }
}
```

Works perfectly. The only problem I have is there is no space after the play icon between the page title and icon. It kind of bothers me. I tried adding the unicode for a space `(+ '\u0020')`, but it doesn't seem to work properly. Can anyone out there help me please? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example you shared has a space after the character they added. They had `\u25B6` whereas you have `\u25BA` (different character code, also no space afterwards.)

Answer (score 0):

Add a space

```
document.title = '\u25BA ' + document.title;
                       ^^^
```

And you need to account for the two letters when you remove it.